# Where in pivot table with Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have set up a table structure like so:

```
+--------+
| colors |
+--------+
| id     |
| hex    |
+--------+

+--------+
| items  |
+--------+
| id     |
| name   | 
+--------+

+------------+
| color_item |
+------------+
| color_id   |
| item_id    |
| user_id    |
+------------+
```

As you can see theres a user_id column in the pivot table. Basically it goes like so. Users can have multiple items, and those items have a set color, which is set per user. So that one user X have item A with color 1, and user Z can have item A with color 2, but user Y can also have item A with color 1, and so on.

I've already set up the relationships in my Laravel application, which means that if i use

```
Item::find(1)->colors()->get()
```

I can get all the colors for that item. But i need to specify a *where* not only on the actual items i get, but also on the relationship, so that in there i only get the colors for the current user. Something like

```
$items = Item::where('other_where_clause')->get();
dd($items[0]->colors->whereInPivot('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id));
```

dd should then output the single color belonging to the user for the first item in the collection.

Is this kind of scenario even possible?

Comment: I don't know laravel but as per your model, how are you preventing an user from having multiple colors for same item?

Comment: The colors table seems kind of redundant. Why not just store the hex in a user_items table?